# Custom post type as home page with custom url

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I've changed the permalinks to add a string at the beginning of the url like this:
/london/%postname%/
This works perfect for all the pages but not for my home page.

I set my home page to be a single custom post type in settings->reading->static page so the url was like this:
http://example.org/destination/london

But now it's:
http://example.org/london/destination/london

How can i change it so the home page is just the single custom post type without the "/destination/london" part?

Edit:

After adding this code it almost work:

```
function enable_front_page_destination( $query ){
    if('' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] && 0 != $query->query_vars['page_id'])
        $query->query_vars['post_type'] = array( 'page', 'destination' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'enable_front_page_destination' );
```

But now the home url is http://example.org/ and it should be http://example.org/london

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Since, as you mentioned it in comments, it can have several values, maybe we could retrieve the city list and set corresponding rewrite rules like so?

assuming $city_list is an array of cities

```
foreach ($city_list as $city) {
    add_rewrite_rule('/^'. $city .'/destination/'. $city .'$/','index.php?p=idofyourhomepage','top');
}
```

How about trying some rewrite rules.

```
add_rewrite_rule('/^london/destination/london$/','index.php?p=idofyourhomepage','top');
```

Or

```
add_rewrite_rule('/^london/destination/london$/','index.php?pagename=nameofyourhomepage','top');
```

Go validate your permalink settings to refresh the rules.

Comment: london is a custom post type so it can have the value london, paris, madrid, etc